# How to open form view in popup without the use of return statement in Odoo-11?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-11

I am working on Odoo-11 and I have an object button that triggers a python method. This method opens a form view in a popup (**target="new"**) and I'm using the **return** statement to achieve that but I want to execute others operations after displaying the popup. How can I display the form view without using the **return** statement?
PS: I tried to use a second method that's responsible for displaying the popup and calling this method within the main method but it doesn't work (see the code below).

```
 @api.multi
def closure(self):
    wizard = self.env['crop_management.warning.wizard']
    warning = wizard.create({'name': "Warning message"})
    self.show_wizard(warning.id)
    if warning.ignore:
        _logger.warning("Yes")
    else:
        _logger.warning("No")

@api.multi
def show_wizard(self, id):
    return {
        'name': _('Warning'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'crop_management.warning.wizard',
        'view_id': False,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id': id,
        'target': 'new',
        'nodestroy': True,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some actions after opening that wizard then from that wizard insert some fields as per your requirement and from button located in wizard on that object type button call your py method. The way you called that not worked so create a popup form view by return statement and then after opening wizard follow steps I suggested so you get your required result.